# Select from text file

Tags: c#, sql

i have list of text file i need to select the contain and importing it to sql, when excel sheet i did it, but with text file it give me error "C:\CETS\filename.TXT' is not a valid path.  Make sure that the path name is spelled correctly and that you are connected to the server on which the file resides."
my code.

```
 string strconn1 = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" 
                    + "Data Source=" 
                    + p_Excel_Path1 
                    + ";Extended Properties='text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited(,)'";

 cmdOledb2.CommandText = "select * from [Sheet1$]";
```

Comment: so what have you checked? Is the file there. Is this on a server? And the file on a client? etc???

Answer (score 2):

To connect to a text file data source using OLEDB 4.0 your connection string's data source parameter needs to specify the full name of the *folder* your text file is in, not the text file itself.  Your SELECT statement will specify the text file name.

So in your assignment to `strconn1`, have your `p_Excel_Path1` variable set to `C:\CETS\` and change your SELECT statement to:

```
select * from [filename.TXT]
```